# After disabling replication, should I disable binary logging?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

I have a master-slave setup currently but am going to remove the replication DB server. The DBs are running on MySQL 5.6. I have a couple of questions about removing the replication:

1) I have read that I have to just run

> *stop slave; reset slave all;*

on the slave and replication will stop, is that all I need to do?

2) I see on my master DB's my.cnf file:

> log-bin=mysql-bin.log
>
> log-slave-updates=1
>
> expire-logs-days = 14
>
> sync-binlog = 1

Should I remove or comment the above lines? Or should I let them be, I don't know if it's useful to keep logging enabled?

Comment: 1) Yes (don't do the reset till you are absolutely sure though). 2) I would say they are potentially very useful (if you need to set up a slave in future, database recovery etc.) Of course they take up a lot of space that you may want to recover. Maybe setting `expire_logs_days` to a lower number (e.g. 3) could be a good compromise?